# Is there any economic meaning to log returns?

Tags: mathematical-economics

I recently had a discussion with a friend regarding log returns and any economic meaning that could have as a measure in the sense of "assessing the benefit received for compensating work done in a previous time period."

He rather suggested that this was a mathematical construct beneficial in constructing stories such as historical var for the assessment of risk (owing to their additive nature.. $\log(a/b)+\log(b/a)$ causing no information loss).

Is there any economic meaning that could be ascribed to log or arithmetic returns?

Comment: I think your friend was right, log return it is just a useful measure with no 'direct' economic interpretation. Arithmetic calculation of return is a simple measure which usually gives you a good estimate of the geometrically calculated return.

Comment: "assessing the benefit received for compensating work done in a previous time period" would refer to **lagged** returns, not log returns. Is there some typo or mis-hearing going on hear that's confused the issue?

Answer (score 13):

Take the 1st order Taylor series the function $log(x)$. around one:
$$ log(x) \approx log(1) + \frac{x-1}{1} = x-1$$

Therefore, for a random variable r that is close to zero:
$$ log(1+r) \approx r$$

Log returns are typically something like $log(P_{new}/P_{old})$:
$$\Delta log(P_t) = log(P_{new}/P_{old}) = log((P_{old} + \Delta P)/P_{old}) = log(1 + \Delta P/P_{old}) \approx \Delta P/P_{old}$$
But $\Delta P/P_{old}$ is just the percent change in $P_{old}$. We've therefore shown that we can approximate the percent change in a variable $X$ with $\Delta log(X)$.

Why bother? Mostly because log differences can be summed but percent changes cannot be:

> Using logs, or summarizing changes in terms of continuous compounding,
>   has a number of advantages over looking at simple percent changes. For
>   example, if your portfolio goes up by 50% (say from \$100 to \$150) and
>   then declines by 50% (say from \$150 to \$75), you’re not back where you
>   started. If you calculate your average percentage return (in this
>   case, 0%), that’s not a particularly useful summary of the fact that
>   you actually ended up 25% below where you started. By contrast, if
>   your portfolio goes up in logarithmic terms by 0.5, and then falls in
>   logarithmic terms by 0.5, you are exactly back where you started. The
>   average log return on your portfolio is exactly the same number as the
>   change in log price between the time you bought it and the time you
>   sold it, divided by the number of years that you held it.

[Jame Hamilton: Use of logarithms in economics](http://econbrowser.com/archives/2014/02/use-of-logarithms-in-economics)

Comment: Derivatives could also aid intuition even though economic data is discrete for obvious reason: $\frac{d\log(p)}{dt} = \frac{d\log(p)}{dp}  \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{1}{p}  \frac{dp}{dt}  = \frac{dp/dt}{p}  $. Where $t$ can be thought of as time and $p$ as a price.